# setState is not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {navigation : ''}
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                  <Navigation onNavigationChange={this.onNavigationChange.bind(this)}/>
                  <main>
                      <TopBar navigation={this.state.navigation}/>
                      <div className="content">
                        <MiddleBar/>
                        {this.props.children}
                      </div>
                      <Footer />
                  </main>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onNavigationChange(selectedValue){
        this.setState({navigation : 'selectedValue'});
        debugger;
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I am passing onNavigationChange callback to my navigation content.Its getting called and returns the value of selected state. But when I try to setState this.setState({navigation : selectedValue}) state is not getting updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.setState({navigation : 'selectedValue'});` doesnt mutate the state directly. From [React doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

So, when `debugger;` is called, `this.state` has not changed yet

Answer (score 0):

onNavigationChange(selectedValue){
        console.log(selectedValue) 
//log the selectedValue if fine correct the //typo below in this.setState to this.setState({navigation : selectedValue});
        this.setState({navigation : 'selectedValue'});
        debugger;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Damien Leroux is right. You can't expect to see the state change immediately within the same event loop.
put the `debugger` in your `render` method to see if your state change triggered a re-render

Just noticed that on this line below

```
this.setState({navigation : 'selectedValue'});
```

looks like you are updating navigation state with a hard coded string `'selectedValue'` instead of the actual value of `selectedValue`